# jQueryMobile horizontal align grid-elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile *Grid system* with five cells. I'd like to have the content of these cells to be aligned to the middle of the cells.

I tried to add:

```
<div style="vertical-align:middle;">text</div>
```

But this didn't work.

Also:

```
<div style="top:50%;">text</div>
```

Didn't work.

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/L4PvC/) to check it out. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: center aligned vertically and horizontally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Display *blocks* as *table* `display: table;` and wrap contents inside each *block* in `p`.

```
<div class="ui-grid-d grids">
  <div class="ui-block-a">
    <p>a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <p>b</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-c">
    <p>c</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-d">
    <p>d</p>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-e">
    <p><a data-role="button" class="ui-link ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" role="button">delete</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the content, display them as *table-cell*, `display: table-cell`, align them *vertically* `vertical-align: middle` and *horizontally* `text-align: center`.

```
.grids {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.grids div { /* all blocks */
  display: table;
  height: 153px;
}

.grids div > p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/JFV2H/)**

Comment: that's exactly what I was after. Thx to Omar as well as Moorthy GK and Tamizh :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `line-height` and `text-align` to make text middle

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsF2f/3/)

Comment: Is it possible to set the button to the middle as well?